# What is the purpose of sphinx.sty and sphinxmanual.cls

Tags: pdf, sphinx

I use sphinx to generate my PDFs, and I do not know what is the purpose of `sphinx.sty` and `sphinxmanual.cls`? Can I modify the two files?

Comment: Welcome. Where can we find the pakage?

Answer (score 3):

Each time you generate a LaTeX file via `make latex` or `make latexpdf`, the package `sphinx.sty` (and others) is copied into the `/build/latex` repertory. You can not modify this file unless you fork the Sphinx project to your own branch. However it has a number of public macros which you can customize via the `'preamble'` key. Please refer to the documentation http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/contents.html and especially http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#options-for-latex-output

Comment: How can I search some directives to customize my own pdf style via 'preamble' key? I want to customize my own pdf style@jfbu